# how to use XAML static resources and design time data in UWP class libraries

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am a programmer with experience in WPF and I am starting to program in UWP.
Almost all of my XAML code is compatible with some exceptions that I have managed to overcome.

At first I tried everything in a stand alone application but now it's time to create reusable user controls, and for that I've created a UWP class library, in which I copied the code of user control that I had programmed and works fine in the App, but in the library it seems that the instances of NET classes are not created in resource dictionaries or in design time data extensions.

This the User Control XAML Code that works in the App but not works in the library (It is the version that uses design time data with "d:") and the problems is that Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top bindings don't get source values (Image appears at Canvas 0,0 positions).

```
<UserControl x:Class="NameSpace.XXXX" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="using:NameSpace" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="355" d:DesignWidth="430">

  <Canvas Height="355" Width="430" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:LocalClass, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
  <Image x:Name="TI11" Source="Assets/Images/Image11.png" Canvas.Left="{Binding T11L}" Canvas.Top="{Binding T11T}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0.65" Height="071.053" Width="064.433"/>

   ......

  </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

I have searched for similar questions, and have seen articles in which independent UWP control libraries are created, but have not found any reference to this problem.

Does anyone know if anything special needs to be done so that static resources NET classes and design time data can be used in a UWP library?

Comment: "but in the library it seems that the instances of NET classes are not created in resource dictionaries or in design time data extensions." Could please describe your issue in a more clearer and detail way? And show some relative code with the "user control" please.

Comment: Although I think instances are not created, it may be that bindings not work in the library for another reason. In a while I'll write the code that fails (when I asked the question I thought it was something simple about UWP that I didn't know, and that it wasn't necessary to write the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is that you don't have to do anything special to use Design Time Data in a UWP library and it should work as in an application.

The problem that raised my question I think is temporary and only affects libraries targeting Fall Creators Update. Until they fix it, **the turnaround is targeting Creators update instead of Fall Creators update**.

The fact is that if you create a UWP library that targets Fall Creators Update with VS 2017 and my sample code, Design Time Data bindings not work.

if you open the library with Blend 2017 and try to use the data window to generate Design Time Data, then Blend informs that the Data Window feature can't be used with projects targeting Fall Creators Update (I attached Blend's message)

[image]

I have reported this problem in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/172286/design-time-data-in-uwp-library-not-working-in-vs.html